# How to maintain and import self-made libraries

Tags: packages, dependencies

Over the years I've written some libraries. These libraries sometimes depend on each other.

As a result, the "tex" directory is structured as follows:

```
tex
├── library
|   ├── library1.sty
|   ├── library2.sty
|   └── library3.sty
├── project1
|   ├── master.tex
|   ├── chapter1.tex
|   └── chapter2.tex
├── project2
|   └── article.tex
└── project3
    └── paper.tex
```

The libraries depend on each other. As a result, in every library that depends on another library, this is part of the header:

```
%library2.sty
\ProvidesPackage{library2}
\RequirePackage{../library/library1}
```

In other words, the library is imported from the "root of every project". This is not a good design choice. What if someone copies the libraries in the folder of the root of a project, or what if the folder "library" is renamed...

It is however reasonable the "active directory" still remains in the project root.

What can be done to resolve such library dependencies?

Comment: Or put them in your personal `texmf` tree at `tex/latex/library/` or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage{../library/library1}
```

should be

```
\RequirePackage{library1}
```

presumably  it makes a warning in the log each time? (unless library 1 has `\ProvidesPackage{../library/library1}`

The Provides Package mechanism is specifically there to enforce that `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` and `\documentclass` take *names* not file paths, to increase portability.

So long as your top level `tex` directory is in `TEXINPUTS` path as `tex//` then all the packages will be found without needing to put machine specific paths into the file.

---

If setting an environment variable is inconvenient, LaTeX has another mechanism, better known as `\graphicspath` but actually applicable to all files.

If you have `mymacros.sty` in a subdirectory `local` which is not in `TEXINPUTS` then `\usepackage{mymacros}` will work if you set the path within latex as:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{local/}}
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mymacros}

\stop
```

where `\input@path` is a list of folders each in a `{}` group, so note the double `{{` for this list of a single `local/` folder.